# How to locate a parent Element in beautiful Soup and delete it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape contents from the webpage: https://www.assamcareer.com/2021/06/oil-india-limited.html, but the issue is that this site has some `<a` links pointing to itself , which I am trying to remove.

Here is the basic HTML structure :

```
<p><strong>Employment Exchange: </strong>Candidates must possess a valid <a href="https://www.assamcareer.com/2021/09/employment-exchange-registration.html"><strong>Employment Exchange Registration</strong></a> Card from specific districts of Assam &amp; Arunachal Pradesh.</p>

<p><span style="font-size:large"><span style="font-family:arial"><span style="font-size:small"><strong><span style="font-size:medium">Districts:</span> </strong>Candidates only from the following districts of Assam can apply for these posts: &nbsp;</span></span></span></p>
```

The first line of html contains the link `assamcareer.com...`. Now how can I:

1. Get the Parent element of any tag that has `**assamcareer.com**` in it
2. Remove that Tag completely

This is what I have tried so far :

```
target = "www.assamcareer.com"
hrefs = [link['href'] for link in getDetails.find_all('a', href=True) if target in link['href']]
if hrefs:
    target.find_parent().decompose()
```

The `getDetails` simply has the entire source of the above listed webpage

> The output should be like this (the tag containing assamcareer.com is **removed**):

```
<p><span style="font-size:large"><span style="font-family:arial"><span style="font-size:small"><strong><span style="font-size:medium">Districts:</span> </strong>Candidates only from the following districts of Assam can apply for these posts: &nbsp;</span></span></span></p>
```

Please provide your valuable Ideas to achieve it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to recreate the html without those tags or just trying to get all of the hrefs other than the ones in those tags?

Comment: I am trying to recreate the HTML other than the tags which has assamcareer.com in it. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

You could first find all the `<p>` tags and then see if any have `<a>` tags containing that href. If found, use `.extract()` to remove the entire `<p>` tag.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p><strong>Employment Exchange: </strong>Candidates must possess a valid <a href="https://www.assamcareer.com/2021/09/employment-exchange-registration.html"><strong>Employment Exchange Registration</strong></a> Card from specific districts of Assam &amp; Arunachal Pradesh.</p>
<p><span style="font-size:large"><span style="font-family:arial"><span style="font-size:small"><strong><span style="font-size:medium">Districts:</span> </strong>Candidates only from the following districts of Assam can apply for these posts: &nbsp;</span></span></span></p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    for a in p.find_all('a', href=True):
        if 'assamcareer.com' in a['href']:
            p.extract()
            break
            
print(soup)
```